# Docker on windows error related to daemon

Tags: docker, window, virtualbox

I am trying to install Docker Tools on Windows 7 laptop, installed Docker using Windows Docker Tools.

When I run `docker run hello-world` I get the below error. I have already removed the VM, and recreated it. Also, I am using a VPN.

Please let me know what steps should I try next.

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.35/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the fi daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running. See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Comment: This may sound obvious, but did you make sure you were running `docker for windows.exe` and `dockercli.exe` as Admin?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the docker service using below on cmd-prompt:

```
Net stop com.docker.service
Net start com.docker.service
```

or restart the Docker for Windows service through the Windows GUI by right clicking the service and choosing restart

Have a look at this [article on success.docker.com](https://success.docker.com/article/docker-for-windows-fails-with-a-daemon-not-running-message)